# How to use Column selection mode Intellij IDE via holding Alt + mouse select?

Tags: intellij-idea

In previous verions of InteliiJ IDEs it was possible just to hold Alt button and column-selection mode was ON (at least MacOS). Right now to enable it you have to switch mode every time on & off by pressing Alt+Shift+8.

How to use column selection only by holding Alt + mouse select? is there any config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to highlight several separate chunks of code (or place multiple carets) at once, you can drag (or click) the mouse while holding `Alt+Shift`. IDEA action name: 'Add or Remove Caret'

Dragging the mouse while holding `Ctrl+Alt+Shift` (`Meta+Alt+Shift` on Mac) will produce a rectangular selection that will also stack with the previous selections. IDEA action name: 'Add Rectangular selection on Mouse Drag'

You can also press `Ctrl` twice, and then without releasing it, press `Up` or `Down` arrow keys.

[This help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html) has a lot of related useful information on the subject.

Comment: Yes, Alt+Shift works! Looks like behaviour changed with latest versions, for. ex.: android studio still has just Alt as it was in the past. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it's `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Click`, no matter whether you are already in column mode or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the keybinding to be **⌥ALT + mouse drag** then you can change the keybindings in **Preferences > Keymap > Editor Actions** like so:

`Create Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` to `⌥ Click`  (clears old cursors)

Note that it should be **Create** instead of **Add**, and if you like you could set

`Add Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` to `⌥ ⇧ Click`  (keeps old cursors)